# How to count specific value from foreach

Tags: php, foreach, count

Could we count specific value from foreach ? 
example :

```
--total--
2
3
4
--total 2--
5
6
7
```

**total** should be : 9

**total 2** shoulb be : 18

This is my view :

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Kode</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Uraian</th>
         <th colspan="3">Rincian Perhitungan</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Jumlah</th>
        <th rowspan="2"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Volume</th>
        <th>Satuan</th>
        <th>Harga Satuan</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    if($belanja)
    foreach (@$belanja as $kode_rek1 => $rek2):?>
    <?php $kode = explode('|', $kode_rek1) ?>
    <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $kode[0]; ?> </strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $kode[1]; ?> </strong></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($rek2 as $kode_rek2 => $rek3):?>
    <?php $kode = explode('|', $kode_rek2) ?>
    <tr>
        <td><strong><?php echo $kode[0]; ?> </strong></td>
        <td><strong><?php echo $kode[1]; ?> </strong></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
        <?php foreach ($rek3 as $kode_rek3 => $rek4):?>
        <?php $kode = explode('|', $kode_rek3) ?>
        <tr>
            <td><strong><?php echo $kode[0]; ?> </strong></td>
            <td><strong><?php echo $kode[1]; ?> </strong></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
            <?php foreach ($rek4 as $kode_rek4 => $rek5):?>
            <?php $kode = explode('|', $kode_rek4) ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $kode[0]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $kode[1]; ?></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
                <?php foreach ($rek5 as $kode_rek5 => $belanja):?>
                <?php $kode = explode('|', $kode_rek5) ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $kode[0]; ?> </strong></td>
                    <td><?php echo $kode[1]; ?></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                    <?php foreach ($belanja as $group => $item):?>  
                    <?php $kode = explode('|', $group) ;
                    if($kode[1]):
                    ?>                                              
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><?php echo $kode[1]; ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>       
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><?php echo anchor('master/kegiatan/delgroup/'.$kode[0], 'DEL', 'class="del"'); ?></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                    endif;
                    //var_dump($item);

                    foreach ($item as $key => $val):
                        if(!is_null($val->id)):?>   
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><?php echo $val->keterangan;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $val->jumlah_satuan;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $val->satuan;?></td>     
                        <td><?php echo number_format($val->nilai_satuan,2,',','.');?></td>
                        <td><?php echo number_format($val->nilai_satuan*$val->jumlah_satuan,2,',','.');?></td>
                        <td><?php echo anchor('master/kegiatan/delrinc/'.$val->id, 'DEL', 'class="del"'); ?></td>

                    </tr>                           
                    <?php 
                    endif;
                    endforeach; ?>
                    <tr>
                        <form class="detil_belanja">

                            <td><?php echo form_hidden('belanja_id', $kode[0]); ?></td>
                            <td><input name="keterangan" placeholder="Keterangan Belanja"></td>
                            <td><input name="volume" placeholder="Jumlah/Volume"></td>
                            <td><input name="satuan" placeholder="Satuan"></td>
                            <td><input name="harga_satuan" placeholder="Harga Satuan"></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" name="" value="ADD" class="btn_submit"></td>
                        </form>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>    
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

this is my controller

```
function detail_belanja($id){
    $this->load->model('kegiatans');

    $belanja =  $this->kegiatans->get_belanja($id);
    foreach ($belanja as $key => $v) {
        $hasil[$v->kd_rek_1_gab][$v->kd_rek_2_gab][$v->kd_rek_3_gab][$v->kd_rek_4_gab][$v->kd_rek_5_gab][$v->kelompok_id.'|'.$v->kelompok][] = $v;
    }
    $data['belanja'] = $hasil;
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($data['belanja']);
    echo '</pre>';
    $this->load->view("bidang/belanja_list",$data);

}
```

This is my model :

```
function get_belanja($id){
    $sql="
    select 
        concat( a.kd_rek_1,'.|',f.nm_rek_1) as kd_rek_1_gab,
        concat( a.kd_rek_1, '.' , a.kd_rek_2,'.|', e.nm_rek_2) as kd_rek_2_gab,
        concat( a.kd_rek_1, '.' , a.kd_rek_2, '.' , a.kd_rek_3,'.|', d.nm_rek_3) as kd_rek_3_gab,
        concat( a.kd_rek_1, '.' , a.kd_rek_2, '.' , a.kd_rek_3, '.' , right(concat('0', a.kd_rek_4), 2),'.|',c.nm_rek_4) as kd_rek_4_gab,
        concat( a.kd_rek_1, '.' , a.kd_rek_2, '.' , a.kd_rek_3, '.' , right(concat('0', a.kd_rek_4), 2) , '.' , right(concat('0', a.kd_rek_5), 2),'.|',b.nm_rek_5) as kd_rek_5_gab,
        concat( a.kd_rek_1, '.' , a.kd_rek_2, '.' , a.kd_rek_3, '.' , right(concat('0', a.kd_rek_4), 2) , '.' , right(concat('0', a.kd_rek_5), 2)) as kode_rekening,
        a.id kelompok_id,a.keterangan kelompok,
      belanja_rinc.*  

from belanja a left join
        belanja_rinc  on belanja_rinc.belanja_id = a.id inner join
        ref_rek_5 b on a.kd_rek_1 = b.kd_rek_1 and a.kd_rek_2 = b.kd_rek_2 and a.kd_rek_3 = b.kd_rek_3 and a.kd_rek_4 = b.kd_rek_4 and a.kd_rek_5 = b.kd_rek_5 inner join
        ref_rek_4 c on b.kd_rek_1 = c.kd_rek_1 and b.kd_rek_2 = c.kd_rek_2 and b.kd_rek_3 = c.kd_rek_3 and b.kd_rek_4 = c.kd_rek_4 inner join
        ref_rek_3 d on c.kd_rek_1 = d.kd_rek_1 and c.kd_rek_2 = d.kd_rek_2 and c.kd_rek_3 = d.kd_rek_3 inner join
        ref_rek_2 e on d.kd_rek_1 = e.kd_rek_1 and d.kd_rek_2 = e.kd_rek_2 inner join
```

ref_rek_1 f on e.kd_rek_1 = f.kd_rek_1 where a.kegiatan_id= ?";

```
        $q = $this->db->query($sql,array($id));
        return $q->result();
}
```

Comment: We don't really need to see ALL your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post a minimal code example which people can copy-paste and play with on their machines.

Comment: sorry XL, im new here.

Comment: Thx georg. Next time i will. So you have any idea for my case ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case IF you want to go with foreach loop then:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($group as $key => $value) {
   $sum += $value; 
}
echo $sum;
```

But if you want to go with direct sum of array than look on below for your solution :

```
$total = array_sum($group);
```